# Is it possible to have Windows 10's interface in language X but have default keyboard-layout to language Y?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, language, user-interface

I'm used to working with everything in English. At the same time I'm in Germany hence I use a German keyboard and a German keyboard-layout.

Now on Linux (at least on Debian-based distros) it's very easy to do this combination and even application-independent (an option that is also available in Windows for my surprise). On Windows 10 this is a nightmare.

In the latest Windows default keyboard-layout and language used for the interface are connected pretty tight. If I change the default order of the keyboard-layouts I have to change the interface language of Windows. Let's not forget the issues I'm facing with spellchecking and the fact that I always have to manually select German in Word etc. as my default language (even though I have explicitely set the spellchecking default language to German!!!). Otherwise I get English by default.

Any idea how to fix this? I just want to type with German keyboard-layout while having Windows in English at the same time. How difficult can this be?

Comment: I use English Windows 10 v1703 and use German keyboard. what is your issue?

Comment: The fact that every time I start a new application it takes the top-most keyboard-layout which is English because the order of the keyboard-layouts is determined by your language settings. That is if I change the order, next time I start Windows I get a German Windows interface.

Comment: I don't have this. During setup of Windows10 I selected German keyboard and I don't see what you have.

Comment: @rbaleksandar - Is it every application or certain applications?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: Every single one. Including the ones developed by Microsoft. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the settings in Control Panel > Clock, Language and Region > Language > Advanced settings. Here you can choose "Override for Windows display language" or "Override for default input method".
[image: Advanced settings control panel]

Comment: It appears to be working. That is until the next major Windows update probably. LOL

Comment: This setting is no longer available in current Windows 10.

Comment: @rbaleksandar You predicted the future.

Answer (score 1):

*(tested on build 1909)*

It is confusing at first, because apparently Keyboard layout settings are now a property of particular Display language options.

1. Go to `Settings` > `Time & Language` > `Language`
2. Press `Add a preferred language` and proceed to install the **display** language, in this case "English (United States)".

*Optional: Remove all **display** languages you don't need.*

3. Once the **display** language is installed, make sure it's on top of the list.
4. Press `Options` > `Add a keyboard` and proceed to install the **keyboard** languages, in your case "German" & "English".

Answer (score 0):

1. Press Win key (aka Magic Key)
2. Type **Language settings**, open it (or use your preferred method to get there)
3. In the Language settings window, scroll down to the **Related settings** header
4. Click on the **Spelling, typing & keyboard settings** link below 'Related settings'
5. Now you have another window opened called **Typing**, scroll down till you see the **More keyboard settings** header
6. Under 'More keyboard settings' you'll see **Advanced keyboard settings**, click on that little rascal too (click-click-click more clicks! not enough clicks! gimme some more clicks and more useless windows Microsoft! I hope you get there before you die because actually part of me died forever while I was looking for that option feeling anger, frustration, and desperation; but, hey, you're not me, I know you can do it, so just keep going, fella! *God Speed*!)
7. By now, you would have a window called 'Advanced keyboard settings' in front of your eyes. And the top thing you see is **Override for default input method**, and it's even written there below:
   'If you want to use an input method that's different than the first one in your language list, choose it here'
   Click on the drop-list-box bellow.
8. Do whatever you came here for and feel all the anger and rage I felt for past 30 years while using all the ugly and apparently far from efficient UX-design solutions made by a bunch of very overpaid sadists who have worked in Microsoft UX-design department all these years. Peace, sis (or bro)!